# How to check what files people are downloading from my server

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check what files people are downloading from my server](https://serverfault.com/questions/247114/how-can-i-check-what-files-people-are-downloading-from-my-server)

I have small server with IIS and Windows Server 2008, hosting one page. Sometimes my bandwidth is completely overloaded. How can I check downloading which files from my server is killing the network connection? Maybe it is swf, maybe some pictures or other files. How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look in `\inetpub\log\logfiles` and you can analyse it with [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/download?ac=ga0108_s_loganalysis&_kk=IIS%20logs&_kt=6e05e8ef-6b23-4029-aab2-83c00318d95e&gclid=CM2yhsTEzacCFYKFpAod-lXCCQ) (which may be over kill), or if its small enough, look through and analyse yourself, or perhaps load it into Excel or something.