# How can I check what files people are downloading from my server

Tags: windows, iis, sql-server-2008

I have small server with IIS and windows server 2008 hosting one page.  Sometimes my bandwidth is completely overloaded.  How can I check what files are being downloaded from my server that is killing my network connection?

Comment: If you do not need to determine the bandwidth statistics programatically, it is a http://serverfault.com/ question. Such informations are usually kept in logs or by some statistics apps.

Comment: First, analyze IIS logs

Answer (score 1):

Look at your IIS logfiles.  By default they're stored in

`%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

You should see an entry for every file that's been downloaded from your website (along with IP addresses and other information)

You can configure which fields are logged in the IIS Manager application.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IIS logs. In some instances you will need to have pre-selected the option for logs to be written. 
If you are watching an actively flooded server, try sysinternals tools available on the web.
Specifically "Process Explorer" to monitor what files are being opened and closed by what processes, and "TCP view" to see what addresses are requesting files.